# Value of the velocity at the largest correlation length in a turbulent medium

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

If a turbulent system is observed to follow a turbulent energy spectrum of the form $E(k)\propto k^{-p}$ for the range $k_{min}<k<k_{max}$, I was wondering if there is a way to have an order of magnitude estimation of the actual velocity (in physical space) at the largest scale (which corresponds to $k_{min}$ in fourier space) for that system.

Comment: The spectrum will stop obeying that power-law at the dissipation scale.  In a neutral fluid like air or water, this will be determined by the scale where viscosity becomes large.  In other systems like the solar wind, it will be determined by electromagnetic waves and other intermittent phenomena.